How can I modify this demo to show the feedback loop of global ice melt?
I am trying to create a classroom demonstration to show the runaway feedback loop of global ice (glaciers, etc.) melting which then exposes darker subsurface which increases the rate of ice melt. We are ignoring the atmospheric aspects and just trying to focus on the albedo effect as it relates to the surface.
I currently have a set up where I have a big block of ice on a 3d printed platform that funnels the icemelt into a cylinder where I have a water level sensor hooked up to an arduino. We have a heat lamp above it to mimic the radiation from the sun. Here is a picture of it:

So far we have just been getting linear ice melt.
Some changes we've made to the set up since the picture.

Thicken the bottom and make it solid to absorb heat.
Make a inverse cone cutout in the ice so a fracture opens up and exposes more of the subsurface.
Make the platform able to tilt more (we were concerned about the water pooling on the platform before dripping into the beaker.
Make the platform much smaller (this was just so I could 3d print it in time to do another run today)

With these changes we still just see a linear ice melt.
Some additional thoughts I have now:

Since we're just using the base to absorb heat for the system, we should make it much wider compared so it's substantially wider than the ice is tall, maybe a couple feet by a couple feet wide. Accordingly, make the ice sheet short, maybe only a couple centimeters thick.
Make cracks in the ice so that fractures can open and widen during the melting, exposing more subsurface.
Try a different subsurface material. I suppose we may want something that better handles and conducts the heat. I am certainly open to ideas here.

So, my question is, with these changes will this set up work or am I missing something critical that will make this not show an exponential curve. Also, what material should I use for the subsurface?

I think your demo suffers from the Square–cube law.

@PM2Ring Which is why I suggested using 200 ice cubes instead of 1 solid block of ice in my answer ;-)

You are initially concluding that there is a runaway feedback loop.  Then, you are attempting to manipulate the variables of your experiment until you get the results you are looking for.  That is the reverse of how the scientific method is done, and it implies that you are attempting to indoctrinate your students.  See the following link: https://sciencenotes.org/steps-scientific-method/

A problem you have in the set-up is that the perimeter of the block is small relative to the total volume of the ice block. The perimeter is where the black substrate is exposed so you need to maximise the perimeter ratio. If the dimensions of your ice block $20\times 20 \times 4 = 1600 \ \text{cm}^3$, the perimeter is $80 \ \text{cm}$. If you replace the ice block with $200$ ice cubes with 2cm sides so that the volume and mass of ice stay the same ($20\times 2^3 = 1600 \ \text{cm}^3$), you increase the perimeter of the ice to $800 \ \text{cm}$ which is $10$ times greater than the original perimeter. This should dramatically increase your ice melt rate. However, this goes away from a realistic model because the poles are better represented by continuous sheets rather than fragmented blocks. I think you should strive for the most realistic model possible so you do not stand accused of exaggerating global warming and misleading your students.
I would definitely make the base plate a solid black metal plate with better heat conduction, similar to the food defrosting trays that you can buy, to accelerate the ambient temperature defrosting of frozen food. I would also make the ice block a cone of ice so there are thin edges that can quickly melt away, exposing the black heat-absorbing substrate more rapidly.
In the real world, the ice melting of the ice caps would be accompanied by a rise in sea level, flooding lowlands and increasing the amount of water area relative to land mass. This would provide a stabilising counter effect as the greater surface area of the water would result in more evaporation of water and a cooling effect. The albedo of the areas newly covered by water would also change due to the presence of the water.
To be more realistic, the base plate should be domed so that water pools and accumulates at the edges and rises up, covering the base plate. (You would have to gauge the rate of ice melting by periodically taking the ice out and weighing it.)

It is going to be very hard to make this demo work because it relies on conduction through plastic to transfer heat from low-albedo to high-albedo regions. Plastic is a very poor conductor of heat, so the conduction is extremely slow, and your ice is probably melting too fast to allow the effects of conduction to become significant.
I think the best bet to make this work is (1) use a metal platform, ideally something like black anodized aluminum, rather than a plastic one; (2) use a solid platform rather than one with slots, because the slots block heat conduction; and (3) make the ice as white as possible, or use snow instead of ice if you can't get white ice.

One source of "white ice" or "snow" would be scrape the frost off the inside of a freezer and compact it into lumps ;-)
